# Gdal for windows 7(x32)

Tags: java, gdal

How do I connect to the gdal eclipse. I tried all the ways it does not work.

How do I connect to the gdal eclipse. I tried all the ways it does not work.
All the time issue
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D: \ Document \ JAVA \ Gdal \ gdalLibrary \ gdaljni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem and just found a solution. I am working with WIN8, and downloaded release-1600-gdal-1-8-0-mapserver-5-6-6.zip. As in the readme txt, I run the SDKShell.bat to set the environment. Then I include the jar and the four jni dlls in the java folder into my testing java project. There was always error like gdaljni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries. Then I figured out the settings in the bat may not been successfully done. I opened up the bat with an editor and found all the necessary enviroment settings and did it one by one. Then the  java project worked with no problem. The settings needed are as follows:

```
SET PATH=%CD%\bin;%CD%\bin\proj\apps;%CD%\bin\gdal\apps;%CD%\bin\ms\apps;%PATH%
SET GDAL_DATA=%CD%\bin\gdal-data
SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%CD%\bin\gdal\plugins
SET PROJ_LIB=%CD%\bin\proj\SHARE
```

For the PATH you can just in explorer right click on computer-properties-advanced system settings-Change enviroment variables. Add the absolute paths(%CD% means the current folder of the bat file, in my case is C:\GDAL, so path "%CD%\bin" should be changed into "C:\GDAL\bin") of "SET PATH line" to your PATH. For the other three lines of settings, just add three system variable for each and aslo change the path containing %CD% into abousolute paths. Then, everything should be ok. Note I omitted some paths in the bat file which I do not need for my java bindings. You can also add them to PATH if you want to do use gdal with other languages. I guess the most common mistake is forgetting to add the GDAL_DRIVER_PATH and PROJ_LIB.Hope it may be helpful for the others who have such issue.

Answer (score 1):

If UnsatisfiedLinkError: gdaljni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries occurs...

1. Check the path of GDAL libraries, data and plugins (they must be in the installation path of your application)
2. Missing VC++2010 runtime (if GDAL is compiled using VC++2010): download the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package:
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84

You may need to set following in the Windows system environment variables:

`GDAL_DATA=<path to gdal-data folder>`

`GDAL_DRIVER=<path to your gdal\plugins folder>`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
1) set path as said above
2) Put the *jni.dll files in the 'The path where you installed gdal'\gdallib\bin\gdal\java\ directories into the jre\bin directories that you are using. (This saved me!)

Hope it will be helpful:)