# How to build gdal jni on windows

Tags: java, gdal, ogr2ogr

I want to use ogr2ogr.java and it need the GDAL jni to work. I have tried following the instruction mentioned here [Build Instructions for GDAL/OGR In Java (Windows)](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructions) but, still I am not able to build it. I am using windows 7 64 bit operating system.
If somebody has build it successfully let me know how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

So, after lot of trouble I found out that that there is no need to build gdal jni from source.

- You can download the compiled jni dll file from here [Tamas Szekeres'
  Windows daily builds](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk). Make sure you
  download a stable release. zip package
  release-1600-x64-gdal-1-8-0-mapserver-5-6-6 worked for me. you can
  can try it too unless you want a very specific version.
- Once the gdaljni.dll file was in place I got the ogr2ogr.java file
  from here [All Java sample
  programs](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/)
- Make sure you check this post to [set the environment variables
  correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21607071/1776145)